# split the url to several parts and get the rest easily

Tags: javascript, node.js

If the url is `https://example.com/web/fundamentals/course/dashboard`

I can split it to an array.

```js
const url = "example.com/web/fundamentals/course/dashboard"
path = url.split("/");
const [head1,head2, ...rest] = path;

console.log(head1);
console.log(head2);
console.log(rest);
```

But how to get the rest as string `fundamentals/course/dashboard`, more than an array without "/" in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const url = "example.com/web/fundamentals/course/dashboard"
path = url.split("/");
const [head1,head2, ...rest] = path;

console.log(head1);
console.log(head2);
console.log(rest.join('/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can join array elements with join.

```
rest.join('/')
```

More info [here](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi5zpG4qNjXAhWPKlAKHbjTDy0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fjoin&usg=AOvVaw3wsBrQV2DMhfQUWMGghJbr)